# как убрать подсказки в jetbrains

Tags: c++, ide, clion, jetbrains

Как убрать подсказки названия переменых в CLion в моем случае ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Соответствующие галочки можно обнаружить в разделе Main menu → Settings → Editor -> Inlay Hints -> С/C++